# Terminal no longer works (at all)

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, glibc

I think I've really done on on myself now.
So, I've been trying to run steam on Lubuntu and upon startup it reports that I'm missing libc.so.6, so specifically I went to the debian package website, downloaded (what I thought was) the right file and dropped it into my `/lib` directory. Now, the problem is that my terminal has completely stopped working, not just a little, but COMPLETELY (nothing can run at all).

Natural question, is there a way I can fix this via live cd? If I need to reinstall, how would I save my data thus-far?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which version of Debian are you using?

Comment: I hope you meant which version of Lubuntu? ;-) ^^^

Comment: Last time I checked, I'm running the 64-bit version of Lubuntu 20.04. Just to clarify, I can't run anything at all, applications don't even start.

Comment: Please elaborate "nothing works at all". Can you go to a terminal by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F1` for example? Can you login? Can you run `ls ~`, `cd /lib`, `sudo su` etc?

Comment: I cannot open the TTY's nor the terminal with CTRL+ALT+T, although the operating system itself seems pretty stable.

Comment: I just realized that using `wget` I accidentally downloaded the html webpage containing the downloads rather than the file itself. Before I closed the only terminal I had open, every command returned a `failed to load shared object`.

Comment: I believe you should try and boot a live USB and see if you can fix the files. This is why you should handle installation of packages through apt, dpkg or other official methods.

Comment: Alright will do, just to check is a live USB actually able to modify what's already on my existing partition or is it local to the USB?

Comment: You should be able to mount your system partition. However, I don't have much experience with it, others here know way more about it than me.

Comment: You can boot the system from a live USB and then mount your hard drive system partition either by terminal command or by clicking on it in the file manager.

Comment: You should provide release details in your question. I see mention of 20.04, so be careful of advice like `lxterminal` which isn't normal for a modern/LXQt Lubuntu (ie. release matters); adding release details to your question avoids that sort of advice (you can edit your own questions).  You mention debian?  Debian & Ubuntu don't mach up (Ubuntu releases in different years & packages never line up just on date let alone differences inside packages), so what exact file (for what release) did you install? For really helpful advice we need clear details which are best placed in your question.

Comment: My bad. I fixed the problem using a live USB and removed the faulty file. For clarification (for the future I guess): I accidentally placed the HTML FILE of the download page into the /lib folder rather than the actual download. Yes, the Lubuntu version was 20.04, and yes I downloaded the file via the debian package website. Forgot that apt-get was a thing, sorry! :)

Comment: I use clonezilla to do a full backup before doing anything risky. it has saved me many times.